# Amazon S3 vs Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I am deciding between Dynamo DB and S3 as a storage solution.

**Current scenario**

1. Low storage requirement
2. non-transactional mostly

(The DB has grown to 15MB only since last 2 years and max I can hope it to grow in the next years is 50-100MB).

**Use cases**

1. I want to query this DB on multiple attributes (secondary indexes as provided by DDB but not in S3, but given the database size i can always perform a full table scan.)
2. Hot-key issue (For this I thought of using L2 cache (cache-out) technique, but some suggested as even this would require network call, I should rather think of having L1 cache.)
3. I have very low Write TPS but high Read TPS (reaches upto 1800 TPS on a single value of key i.e single record )

I am considering DDB because of its scalability and its maintenance, and indexing support. And S3 because files are not regularly updated. My current design model is such that every time there's an update I create a fresh entry.

Suggestions please !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a small database (100MB), high Read TPS and low Write TPS, then you should consider keeping the data in RAM, backed by any storage method.

Some options:

- Amazon Elasticache
- [Amazon DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX)](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-dynamodb-accelerator-dax-in-memory-caching-for-read-intensive-workloads/)

Comment: Thanks ! I had been considering Elasticache for long, DAX also seems a good option.

Comment: Another thing.. It seems DAX is supposed to be used only with Dynamo DB, can i have a solution, where I am keeping my data only in Cache?  For secondary indexing and searching I'll have to look for some API.

Comment: If you only want to keep data in the cache, use Amazon Elasticache. The Redis option is the most capable and popular.

Comment: Hey, another suggestion, please. So I finalized on Dynamo DB+ DAX. But since the size of db is small, I am thinking to use a common hash as the partition key (and timestamp as sort key), so that the complete table is saved in a single partition only. But I also intend to create GSIs, so I was wondering whether it would be wrong to use GSIs for single partition. Need an urgent help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: That might be worth of asking as a separate question to get advice from DyanmoDB experts.